Photos do not display when the application is moved to production
I have an application on shared hosting. The uploaded images are located in the storage\public\actors directory. On localhost everything worked ok, but on production it doesn't anymore (I changed the paths in index.php). Interestingly uploading images works fine, only they don't display in the view. A 404 error is reported.This is how I tried to insert the photo
<img src=‘{{ Storage::url(’actors/‘ . $actor->thumb) }}’>
<img src=‘{{ asset(’storage/app/public/actors/‘ . $actor->thumb) }}’>

It's the same every time. I've also tried creating a link to the storage php artisan storage:link, I've also changed the filesystem in .env from local to public, but I keep getting the same thing and I'm starting to run out of ideas.
How can I display the photos in the view?
@Edit
.env
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=***
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=***

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_FAKER_LOCALE=en_US

APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER=file
APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE=database

BCRYPT_ROUNDS=12

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_STACK=single
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=***
DB_USERNAME=***
DB_PASSWORD=c***

SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=null

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=log
FILESYSTEM_DISK=public
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

CACHE_STORE=database
CACHE_PREFIX=

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailpit
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7700

MEILISEARCH_NO_ANALYTICS=false

filesystem
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application for file storage.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Below you may configure as many filesystem disks as necessary, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks for the same driver. Examples for
    | most supported storage drivers are configured here for reference.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];


Have you right-clicked and inspected the URLs of the images to see where they point to?

Yes but I'm not sure which url address will be correvtly. For example - in localhost address localhost/actors/exampe.webp display img but in production example.com localhost/actors/exampe.webp and I don't know why.

Are you saying the URLs in production are the same as on your dev system (http://localhost/actors/exampe.webp), or are you saying they are like http://example.com/localhost/actors/exampe.webp? Either way, it sounds as if you probably failed to update some config setting / env variable that specifies a base URL or base path.

I updated my post. Could you look at this?

please try to run this cmd:
php artisan storage:link and also make sure you Set Correct Permissions  chmod -R 755 storage
chmod -R 755 public/storage

Nope. I used php artisan storage:link befire and I changed chmod. Especially as, if it were a problem with permissions, I would not be getting a 404 error.
